# Django validate formatted date

Tags: django, jquery-ui, django-forms

I'm using jquery.ui.datepicker on a django form.

I'm formatting the date with: `DateInput(format='%b %d, %Y')`

And in the model, it's defined as: `models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)`

But a date formatted as 'Aug 6, 2014' fails. How do I get it to validate on the form `save` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use clean method from  your form to check a field. Assume that you datefield is called mydate,  you can write a method in your form called def clean_mydate(dict) and over there check the date and raise any error if you need it.

That is the correct way to validate form fields.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Or if you want to override your form save method, you need to add something like this in your form:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    instance = super(MyForm, self).save(commit=False)
    my_date= self.cleaned_data['mydate']
     // do some checks and raise errors
    if commit:
        instance.save()
    return instance
```